# Why my .env variable file is not relate node app

Tags: javascript, node.js, api, axios, localhost

I am desperately looking a way to run [my node app](https://github.com/codebubb/job-search-app) with my adzuna api keys, my app must be able to fetch data (json) from adzuna:

`JobSearch.js` is my main js file

```
configureFormListener() {
  this.searchForm.addEventListener('submit', (event) => {
  event.preventDefault();
  this.startLoading();
  this.resultsContainer.innerHTML = '';
   const { search, location } = extractFormData(this.searchForm);
   fetch(`http://localhost:3000/?search=${search}&location=${location}&country=${this.countryCode}`)
     .then(response => response.json())
     .then(({ results }) => {
       this.stopLoading();
       return results
      .map(job => jobTemplate(job, this.currencySymbol))
      .join('');
  })
  .then(jobs => this.resultsContainer.innerHTML = jobs)
  .catch(() => this.stopLoading());
 });
}
```

I understood that `server.js` complete `config.js`

```
const server = createServer((req, res) => {
 const requestURL = url.parse(req.url);
 const decodedParams = decodeParams(new URLSearchParams(requestURL.search));
 const { search, location, country = 'gb' }  = decodedParams;

 const targetURL = `${config.BASE_URL}/${country.toLowerCase()}/${config.BASE_PARAMS}&app_id=${config.APP_ID}&app_key=${config.API_KEY}&what=${search}&where=${location}`;
  if (req.method === 'GET') {
  console.log(chalk.green(`Proxy GET request to : ${targetURL}`));
  axios.get(targetURL)
    .then(response => {
      res.writeHead(200, headers);
      res.end(JSON.stringify(response.data));
    })
    .catch(response => {
      console.log(chalk.red(response));
      res.writeHead(500, headers);
      res.end(JSON.stringify(response));
    });
  } 
});
```

I am a beginner on nodeJS so i suppose that need separated the property & api keys for the encapsulation & safety

`config.js :`

```
 require('dotenv').config()
 module.exports = {
   APP_ID: process.env.APP_ID,
   API_KEY: process.env.API_KEY,
   BASE_URL: 'https://api.adzuna.com/v1/api/jobs',
   BASE_PARAMS: 'search/1?&results_per_page=20&content-type=application/json',
 };
```

`.env :`

```
APP_ID="000000000000000"
API_KEY="000000000000000
```

...But i dont know is a localhost port error or maybe it dosent happens to take the api keys values, because when I run the search request `http://localhost:3000/?search=...`  it made me net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED and the `accessKeyId` section's browser is always empty

[image]

What's wrong with my code ?

Comment: What does the server console say? Can you see the proper URL?

Comment: @chris-g i have this : > frontend@1.0.0 dev > parcel index.html Server running at localhost:1234 ✨ Built in

Comment: @Noob-Dev95 If the server is running at port 1234 you should change your frontend code to reflect the correct port, in the frontent you're querying in the port 3000

Comment: @Giancarl021 I need to change the port on the file project or on my PC setting ??

Comment: What I mean is, when you go to localhost:1234 and submit a search, what does it say in the terminal where you started the node backend? Does it receive the fetch request at all?

Comment: @Noob-Dev95 Change on the frontend project. Anyplace querying localhost:3000 should be changed to reflect the 1234 port. You also can change the server port on the Node project to 3000

Comment: @giancarl021 i replace every thing on the project who are related to `3000` by `1234` but still have localhost/3000... net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED 

Comment: @chris-g absolutely anything on my terminal !, pls look my share video to see that: https://drive.google.com/file/d/194IhYS9zy_7fTK5-sJxSKurXCzfKFc4Q/view?usp=sharing

Comment: I see, your *backend* is running on port 1234. Like the others said, change the frontend code's requests to localhost:1234/..., in the video you posted it's still making requests to 3000, which obviously won't work if your server is running on 1234. Also: you can remove the server and port part from your fetch urls, and use [this](https://parceljs.org/features/development/#api-proxy) instead, that way you don't have to change the port all over the place. This will also enable you to publish the app without changing it *again*.

Comment: @ChrisG @giancarl021 I've just find the tutorial video about the guy made this work, but for him it working well with `localhost/3000`  `localhost/1234`  that weirdo... https://drive.google.com/file/d/1cCKtvZaD8E1qOLTb5O1FNOd5jPYzdBbR/view?usp=sharing